# How to solve one linear algebra equation with 2 unknowns using Python

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

Trying to solve problem of 2 investments with 2% and 4% annual interest respectively. If $10,000 total was originally invested and the account had $10,250 at year end, what was the principal in each investment. I've tried using the solve function

This is the equation I came up with to represent the problem.
1.04x+1.02y=10000 * 1.025

However I'm not sure that I'm properly placing the coefficients into the arrays.

This is the code I set up:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1.0,1.0],[104,102]])
Y = np.array([[1.025],[10000.0]])
np.linalg.solve(A, Y)
```

I'd expect the results to be $7500 and $2500 which satisfy the equation and up to $10,250, however running my code I get:

```
array([[ 4947.725],
       [-4946.7  ]])
```

Comment: What package is the `solve` function coming from?  It's not a `python` built-in.

Comment: One equation with two unknowns has no single solution.  You need two linear equations to get a unique solution with two unknowns.

Comment: A better explanation of the mathematics of equations and unknowns etc etc might be obtained over at [math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: The solve function is a part of numpy.

Comment: `numpy` also has no `solve` method.  Presumably it is the one in [`numpy.linalg`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html)?

Comment: yes, that's correct sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misswrote your matrix system:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1.0,1.0],[1.04,1.02]])
Y = np.array([[10000.0],[10250.0]])
np.linalg.solve(A, Y)
>>>array([[2500.], [7500.]])
```

Which is what you expected

Comment: Thanks the worked perfectly! I knew it had to be an issue with the way I was writing them.